# Show excluded point topology is a topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm teaching my self topology with the aid of a book. I'm trying to prove the following is a topology:

> Let X be an infinite set, and $p$ be an arbitrary point in $X$.
>  Show that $\mathscr{T}_4=\{U \subseteq X : U = X $ or $ p \notin U \} $ is a topology.

My book calls this the [excluded point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excluded_point_topology)

Please let me know if my proof is valid.

Now to verify the definition.

> (i) X and Ø are elements of $\mathscr{T}$.

X is given in the definition of $\mathscr{T}_4$, and $p \notin \varnothing$, by definition. So (i) is "self-evident."

> (ii) $\mathscr{T}$ is closed under finite intersections.

Let: $ A = \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i ; $ where $U_i$ are sets that do not contain $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. $A$ must be in $\mathscr{T}_4$ because intersections are the points that sets have in common, and none of the $U_i$'s contains $p$.

*special case*: $A \cap X$. This is still in $\mathscr{T}_4$ because  $A \cap X = A$ .

> (iii) $\mathscr{T}$ is closed under arbitrary unions.

Let: $A=\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ where $U_i$ are sets that do not contain $p$. $A$ will be in $\mathscr{T}_4$ because unions take all the elements of their constitutive parts, and none of the $U_i$'s contains $p$.

*special case*: $A \cup X$. This is still in $\mathscr{T}_4$ because  $A \cap X = X$ .

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: Almost, but not quite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (ii) and (iii) you should also account for intersections and unions of families that include the open set $X$. For (ii), for instance, let $\mathscr{U}$ be a finite family of open sets. If there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $p\notin U$, then clearly $p\notin\bigcap\mathscr{U}\subseteq U$. If not, then $\mathscr{U}=\{X\}$, and $\bigcup\mathscr{U}=X\in\mathscr{T}$. For (iii) let $\mathscr{U}$ be an arbitrary family of open sets. If $X\in\mathscr{U}$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{U}=X\in\mathscr{T}$, and if not, then $p\notin U$ for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$, so $p\notin\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\mathscr{T}$.

The special cases involving $X$ are even more obvious than the cases that you did cover, but they should still be dealt with.

Comment: Good point,Brian. Technically,the proofs aren't complete without these cases. You could assume X is in the unions and intersections since they're arbitrary, but it's by no means obvious.My bad.

Comment: Thank you, I totally over looked that. I just added a special case to (ii) and (iii)

Comment: @Michael: You’re welcome.